# Write method to handle on click in a listview android

Tags: android, listview, dropdownbox

I am fetching search results from my server and displaying them in a listview. Firstly, I need to change this into a scrollable dropdown. The values in the dropdown are in the format:
SchoolA ;  Russia
I need to capture this text on click and split it into SchoolA and Russia. 
The code is as follows in activity page:

```
private void populateResults(String response) {

List<String> resultsFromServer = parseResponse(response);

ListView resultsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.schoolssListView);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultsFromServer); 
resultsList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

addListenerOnClick(); // this is the method in which i need the above mentioned operations}
```

Now, the code in the xml page for listview is as below:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/schoolssListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

   // Your code here , position points to your requirement index

}

});
```

Onclick you can get the position of the item ,Get the String from the arrayList of that position so you will get Eg: `StringA;Russia` Then split it with seperator `;` and use it

**UPDATE**

```
String currentString = "StringA;Russia";

String[] separated = CurrentString.split(";");
separated[0]; // it will contain StringA
separated[1]; // it will contain russia
```

Alternate

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(CurrentString, ":");

String first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "StringA"
String second = tokens.nextToken();
```

Comment: isn't this still a list? it won't be a dropdown for the search box.

Comment: For a dropdown you should keep a button and a listView

Comment: also, can you please tell how to use stringsplit method on the text at that position ?

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92) is one example to implement Custom List View and overriding onItemclick on listview in android

Hope this will help.You can ask if you have any further queries.